# Dealing with à in generating code for a string literal using Python 3.5's AST module, need to open with right coding

Tags: python, transcrypt

To generate JavaScript from Python in the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org/) Python to JS compiler, Python 3.5's ast module is used in combination with the following code:

```
class Generator (ast.NodeVisitor):
    ...
    ...

    def visit_Str (self, node):
        self.emit (repr (node.s))  # Simplified to need less context on StackOverflow

    ...
    ...
```

This works fine e.g. for the following line of Python:

```
test = "âäéèêëiîïoôöùüû"
```

which is correctly translated to:

```
var test = 'âäéèêëiîïoôöùüû';
```

Only the character à gives problems:

```
test = "àâäéèêëiîïoôöùüû"
```

is translated to:

```
var test = 'Ĝxa0âäéèêëiîïoôöùüû';
```

Is there any way to have the ast module read the source file respecting coding directives like:

```
# coding=<encoding name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a Python file for parsing, use

```
tokenize.open
```

rather than the ordinary

```
open
```

function.

It will open, read the pep263 coding hint and return the open file as if it were opened by the ordinary `open` using the right encoding.

Quite hard to find, not currently in the Green Tree Snakes doc. Actually found it by searching for 'coding' in the CPython sources on GitHub.

Have created an issue for Green Tree Snakes doc to add this.